# Starting nestjs in production mode

Tags: nestjs

I am using akveo backend bundle that I bought, and while everything seems to be working fine in development mode starting in production gives me following errors, I am new to nestjs itself. 
Anyone know what's going here?

```
node_modules/@nestjs/core/adapters/http-adapter.d.ts:5:31 - error TS2420: Class 'AbstractHttpAdapter<TServer, TRequest, TResponse>' incorrectly implements interface 'HttpServer<TRequest, TResponse>'.
    Property 'status' is missing in type 'AbstractHttpAdapter<TServer, TRequest, TResponse>' but required in type 'HttpServer<TRequest, TResponse>'.

5 export declare abstract class AbstractHttpAdapter<TServer = any, TRequest = any, TResponse = any> implements HttpServer<TRequest, TResponse> {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    node_modules/@nestjs/common/interfaces/http/http-server.interface.d.ts:26:5
    26     status(response: any, statusCode: number): any;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'status' is declared here.

    node_modules/@nestjs/core/application-config.d.ts:2:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common/interfaces/configuration-provider.interface'.

    2 import { ConfigurationProvider } from '@nestjs/common/interfaces/configuration-provider.interface';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    node_modules/@nestjs/core/guards/guards-context-creator.d.ts:3:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common/interfaces/configuration-provider.interface'.

3 import { ConfigurationProvider } from '@nestjs/common/interfaces/configuration-provider.interface';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-context-creator.d.ts:2:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common/interfaces/configuration-provider.interface'.

2 import { ConfigurationProvider } from '@nestjs/common/interfaces/configuration-provider.interface';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.d.ts:24:5 - error TS2416: Property 'getHttpAdapter' in type 'NestApplication' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'INestApplication'.
    Type '() => AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>' is not assignable to type '() => HttpServer<any, any>'.
    Property 'status' is missing in type 'AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>' but required in type 'HttpServer<any, any>'.

24     getHttpAdapter(): AbstractHttpAdapter;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    node_modules/@nestjs/common/interfaces/http/http-server.interface.d.ts:26:5
26     status(response: any, statusCode: number): any;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'status' is declared here.


    Found 5 errors.
```

I am using `tsc -p tsconfig.build.json` command to build it with `tsconfig.build.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

and `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I expect that this config should compile typescript code to javascript which then I would run with `node dist/main.js` command. Which it actually does. But I am worried about the typescript compiler errors.

Comment: Please paste your errors in StackOverflow. The picture is hard to read and discourages others from helping. 

What start commands are you using? How are you building your project? How are you testing the deployment? Where are you trying to deploy to (if you are deploying your server currently)?

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in mind in the future. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure without the code but got similar mismatches once upon a time in nest core packages. Check out `package.json` and ensure that all `@nest` packages have the same version, as sometimes they have 'breaking' changes even if it wasn't major release.

For an abstract example, something like that gave me errors related to `core` when building production:

```
   "@nestjs/common": "6.6.0",  // notice the core/common does not match, it should be bumped
   "@nestjs/core": "6.6.2",
```

Comment: It turned out that this indeed was, the problem. Although now I am having with nestjs not been able to resolve mongoose @InjectModel dependencies. But this is another issue.